# Alignment issue in the /users page entries

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, users-page

Currently in the [`/users`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) page, the location detail and badge detail are displaying in two lines. It is not good for readability. Previoulsy both are displayed in single line.

> [image: Alignment issue]

When inspect the element, the CSS class `.user-info` has fixed `width: 200px`. Removing the width, the UI is displaying as expected.

> [image: Expected]

Can this be corrected to look like old UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This alignment issue has been fixed per your suggestion. It now looks like this:

> [image: screenshot]